# Check if lineEdit input has right format Qt 5 C++

Tags: c++, string, qt

I need to check if input text in QLineEdit is in this format aaa@b where "aaa" can bee BE,WE,TZ,WB,CON,ZWL,SCL,KC1 and "b" can be B or G...

But in input text i can put "aaa@b,aaa@b,aaa@b" then MUST comma be after >>@b<<<

Comment: I can make this with trimming string by comma and check substring before @ and after @ for each trimmed string but i hope there is a much simpler answer for this

Comment: I would say that that's a perfectly good solution if ot works.. I don't think anyone will write the code for you here.

Comment: @Pecurka, looks like it's time to learn how to use Regex: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qregexp.html

Comment: you can check qt docks for QRegExpValidator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regular expression you can check this.
Ex:

```
QRegExp regex("^((BE|WE|TZ|CON|ZWL|SCL|KC1)@(B|G)(,|$))+");
QLineEdit le;
le.setText("WE@G");
le.text().contains(regex); // return true
le.setText("BE@BSCL@G,KC1@B");
le.text().contains(regex); // return false
le.setText("BE@B,SCL@G,KC1@B");
le.text().contains(regex); // return true
```